# How do I set the width of a fixed element to fit the whole page?

Tags: css, styles, html, css-position

This is the html file:[image: index.html]

and this is the css file:[image: stylesheet]

This produces the following result:[image: result]

How do I set the header class such that the width would be that of the footer?
It is possible if the position of the header is not fixed but once the position is set to fixed, the width is not set? How do i solve this? I need the header to be fixed so it doesn't move when scrolled down.

[Edit]
I have changed the width to 100% and this is the result:
[image: result]
Is it just my browser that shows the header with a bit  of margin on the left but none on the right when it is set to 100%?

Comment: Instead of code screenshots, post the real code

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your header class should work...

```
width: 100%;
```

By setting the header to be fixed positioned you are taking it out of the natural flow of the page. So rather than it automatically filling the width of its parent () it default to the width of it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
.header{
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
border: none;
etc...
}
```